# Angular hide an element on blur

Tags: angularjs

I got two elements paragraph and input tag. When i click the paragraph, the input should show and paragraph should hide. when the input is blurred the input should hide and paragraph should show.
I tried this but not working

```
<p ng-click="edit = true" ng-show="!edit">some text</p>
<div ng-show="edit" ng-blur="edit = false">
    <input type=text name="email" ng-blur="blurUpdate()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is it a typo in the question or did you really forget the `=` after `ng-blur`? Also, try to put the `ng-blur` on the `input` rather than the `div`.

Comment: Sorry its a typo in question. I got icons inside div. I want them too hide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `ng-blur` to `input` please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {


  $scope.showEditor = function() {

    $scope.edit = true;

    var textbox = document.getElementById("input_email");

    var tmp = $scope.text
    $scope.text = ""

    $timeout(function() {
      textbox.focus();

      $scope.text = tmp;


    });





  }

  $scope.blurUpdate = function() {


    // add this line 
    $scope.edit = false;


    //your code

  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl" ng-init="text='some text'">
    <p ng-click="showEditor()" ng-show="!edit">{{text}}</p>
    <div ng-show="edit">
      <input type=text name="email" ng-blur="blurUpdate()" ng-model="text" id="input_email" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention i have another function in input blur. how to set now. Question Edited

Comment: Its showing. good but also I need its focus. Right now i need to click twice to get focus of input.

Comment: @AbelD that's a topic for other question :) but I'm sure it was asked many times already here so you can easily find solution here

Answer (score 1):

the ngBlur is compatible with input tag, that is why it is not working:

```
<p ng-click="edit = true" ng-show="!edit">some text</p>
<div ng-show="edit" >
<input type=text ng-blur="edit = false" name="email" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgp2qsww/1/

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention i have another function in input blur. how to set now. Question Edited

Comment: Then you should change approach:
http://jsfiddle.net/xgp2qsww/3/

The ngBlur on the div is not useful. The function blurUpdate has to change the $scope.edit in order to perform what you seek

Comment: Its showing. good but also I need its focus. Right now i need to click twice to get focus of input.

Comment: An easy-clean solution could be to set:
ngIf on the div and add a little directive that add the focus on the init of the input. This solution creates and deletes the input each time though
http://jsfiddle.net/xgp2qsww/5/